# Display image based on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How do I display the selected image only?
So what I wanted to happen is that I have set of buttons where the customer do customize the image.

E.g. User choose shapes as circle then displays, then there's next step where user will choose patter then displays inside the circle. 
For the Shapes, i have the idea that the transparent part is only inside (applies to circle,rectangle and heart)

here's my code:

```js
function display(){

if (document.getElementById('shape1').checked)   
    {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('display_image').getContext('2d');
    var imageObj = new Image();
     imageObj.onload = function()
     {  ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0); }
     
     imageObj.src = 'http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/33/33848.png';
     }
     
     
     if (document.getElementById('shape2').checked)   
    {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('display_image').getContext('2d');
    var imageObj = new Image();
     imageObj.onload = function()
     {  ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0); }
     
     imageObj.src = 'http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/33/33848.png';
     }
}

     if (document.getElementById('pattern1').checked)   
    {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('display_image').getContext('2d');
    var imageObj = new Image();
     imageObj.onload = function()
     {  ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0); }
     
     imageObj.src = 'https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTw_LgFWAcL6RzFH4EApgo69TX7xx6iUyPqLANgi5qdJ6QL9CY';
     }
}

     if (document.getElementById('pattern2').checked)   
    {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('display_image').getContext('2d');
    var imageObj = new Image();
     imageObj.onload = function()
     {  ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0); }
     
     imageObj.src = 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/8b/09/59/8b0959d17298294904713dbb94b00827.png';
     }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <form role="form" id="showchoices" name="showchoices" method="post">

<div> <input type="radio" id="shape1" name="shape_design" value="CIRCLE" onchange="display()"/> O 
<input type="radio" id="shape2" name="shape_design" value="RECTANGLE" onchange="display()"/> [] </div>

<div> <input type="radio" id="pattern1" name="pat_design" value="pattern2" onchange="display()"/> pattern1  
<input type="radio" id="pattern2" name="pat_design" value="pattern1" onchange="display()"/> pattern2 </div> -- i would like the pattern not to overlap the shape, send to back and visible.
</form>

<div id="display_image" name="display_image" width="400px" height="400px"> </div>
```

The idea is something like this but without the animation .
Radio button do triggers to display the images, just static display. 
-- http://jsfiddle.net/djnBD/

and I'm combining this process to this sample too - https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/955j8so3/27/

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!!!

Comment: Your snippet has syntax errors and `getContext('2d')` is a canvas API, yet there is no canvas in your code.

Comment: Why do you use canvas? If you are loading predefined images as I see from `imageObj.src = 'http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/33/33848.png';` then why don't you just append the images in your DOM and play with their z-index and positioning?

Comment: @chazsolo at first I was using canvas, but now I wanted to get rid of it.

Comment: @StavrosAngelis how do i simply display it without using the canvas api?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short example of how you could make what you want with HTML and jQuery. Hope it helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click", "*[data-toggle='add-img']", function() {
 var newImgSrc  = $(this).attr("data-img"); 
 var newImgId   = $(this).attr("data-img-id"); 
 var newImg     = "<img src='"+newImgSrc+"' id='"+newImgId+"' />";
 appendToContainer(newImg, newImgId);
  });
  $(document).on("click","*[data-toggle='remove-img']", function() {
    var newImgId  = $(this).attr("data-img-id"); 
    if ($("#"+newImgId).length>0) $("#"+newImgId).remove();
  });
   
  function appendToContainer(img, imgId) {
  var imgContainer = $("#images-container"); 
  var zIndex  = imgContainer.children("img").last().css("z-index");
  var newZIndex  = parseInt(zIndex)+1;
  if ($("#imgId").length===0) imgContainer.append(img);
  $("#imgId").css({"z-index":newZIndex});
  }
});
```

```css
#images-container > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="add-img" data-img="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/33/33848.png" data-img-id="img1">img 1</a>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="add-img" data-img="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTw_LgFWAcL6RzFH4EApgo69TX7xx6iUyPqLANgi5qdJ6QL9CY" data-img-id="img2">img 2</a>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="add-img" data-img="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/8b/09/59/8b0959d17298294904713dbb94b00827.png" data-img-id="img3">img 3</a>
  
  <a href="#" data-toggle="remove-img" data-img-id="img1">delete img 1</a>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="remove-img" data-img-id="img2">delete img 2</a>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="remove-img" data-img-id="img3">delete img 3</a>
</div>

<div id="images-container"></div>
```

Comment: thank you! I got the idea of almost what I've wanted, but a little buggy here. I wanted to completely remove the rectangle when I'll choose circle.

Comment: You could add some rules in the appendToContainer function like `if (imgId==="circle" && $("#rectangle").length >0) {$("#rectangle").remove()};`

Answer (score 0):

i tried using canvas, got it right now:

```js
function display(){

if (document.getElementById('shape1').checked)   
    {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('display_image').getContext('2d');
    var imageObj = new Image();
     imageObj.onload = function()
     {  ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0); }
     
     imageObj.src = 'http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/33/33848.png';
     }
     
     
     if (document.getElementById('shape2').checked)   
    {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('display_image').getContext('2d');
    var imageObj = new Image();
     imageObj.onload = function()
     {  ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0); }
     
     imageObj.src = 'http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/33/33848.png';
     }
}

     if (document.getElementById('pattern1').checked)   
    {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('display_image').getContext('2d');
    var imageObj = new Image();
     imageObj.onload = function()
     {  ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0); }
     
     imageObj.src = 'https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTw_LgFWAcL6RzFH4EApgo69TX7xx6iUyPqLANgi5qdJ6QL9CY';
     }
}

     if (document.getElementById('pattern2').checked)   
    {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('display_image').getContext('2d');
    var imageObj = new Image();
     imageObj.onload = function()
     {  ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0); }
     
     imageObj.src = 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/8b/09/59/8b0959d17298294904713dbb94b00827.png';
     }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



 <form role="form" id="showchoices" name="showchoices" method="post">

<div> <input type="radio" id="shape1" name="shape_design" value="CIRCLE" onchange="display()"/> O 
<input type="radio" id="shape2" name="shape_design" value="RECTANGLE" onchange="display()"/> [] </div>

<div> <input type="radio" id="pattern1" name="pat_design" value="pattern2" onchange="display()"/> pattern1  
<input type="radio" id="pattern2" name="pat_design" value="pattern1" onchange="display()"/> pattern2 </div> -- i would like the pattern not to overlap the shape, send to back and visible.
</form>

<canvas id="display_image" name="display_image" width="400px" height="400px"> </canvas>
```

It might won't work here but its already fine in my codes.